# Save AJAX data to WP table as JSON

Tags: php, json, ajax, wordpress

I've setup a function and some jQuery that takes a value from a form a user submits, and sends it to the database successfully in it's own table. However, I'm trying to set it up to save the data as JSON instead (so as to make sure my WP table doesn't balloon to an unbearable size in the future).

Function here:

```
function search_modifications_callback() {

// Ensure we have the data we need to continue
if( ! isset( $_POST ) || empty( $_POST ) || ! is_user_logged_in() ) {

    header( 'HTTP/1.1 400 Empty POST Values' );
    echo 'Could Not Verify POST Values.';
    exit;
}

$user_id = get_current_user_id();  // Get our current user ID
$search_term  = $_POST['saved_search'];

update_user_meta( $user_id, 'saved_search', $search_term ); // Add our user meta


wp_update_user( array(
    'ID'            => $user_id
) );

exit;
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_search_ss', 'search_modifications_callback' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_search_ss', 'search_modifications_callback' );
```

jQuery here:

```
// Form submission listener
jQuery( '#save-search' ).click( function() {

    // Grab our post meta value
    var ss_val = jQuery( '#save_search_term' ).val();
    var user_id = jQuery( '#user_id' ).val();

    // Do very simple value validation
    if( jQuery( '#save_search_term' ).val() ) {
        jQuery.ajax( {
            url : ajax_url,                 
            type: 'POST',                   
            data: {                         
                action  : 'search_ss',          
                id: user_id,
                'saved_search': ss_val,       
            }
        } )
        .success( function( results ) {
            console.log( 'User Meta Updated!' );
            alert('Search saved!');
        } )
        .fail( function( data ) {
            console.log( data.responseText );
            console.log( 'Request failed: ' + data.statusText );
        } );

    } else {

    }

    return false;   // Stop our form from submitting
} );
```

I understand that instead of using 'update_user_meta' I should probably create an object instead, but am unsure how to properly set that up from here.

Open to other suggestions as well. Thanks!

Comment: From your current code, there will be only one `saved_search` record per user in the `wp_usermeta` table so I wouldn't worry about the database growing too big (unless you're expecting to have billions of users registered in your site?)

Comment: Hey cabrerahector, you've got a point. Ideally I want to extend this out so that each user has something like, up to 3 or 5 or X many searches available to them down the road. Previously I was using 'add_user_meta'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking your comment above into consideration, if you plan to save up to N search terms per user then I'd do something like this:

```
function search_modifications_callback() {

    // Ensure we have the data we need to continue
    if( ! isset( $_POST ) || empty( $_POST ) || ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
        header( 'HTTP/1.1 400 Empty POST Values' );
        echo 'Could Not Verify POST Values.';
        exit;
    }

    $user_id = get_current_user_id();  // Get our current user ID
    $search_term  = $_POST['saved_search'];

    // Get user's saved search terms
    $user_saved_search_terms = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'saved_search' );

    // User has some previously saved search terms
    if (
        $user_saved_search_terms
        && is_array( $user_saved_search_terms )
        && !empty( $user_saved_search_terms )
    ) {

        // This search term doesn't exist in our saved search terms array yet, so let's add it
        if ( !in_array($search_term, $user_saved_search_terms) ) {
            $user_saved_search_terms[] = $search_term;

            /**
             * You'll want to add here some logic
             * to limit the array to N search terms
             *
             * For example:
             */

            /*
            // User has more than 5 saved search terms already,
            // let's remove the oldest one
            if ( count($user_saved_search_terms) > 5 ){
                $user_saved_search_terms = array_shift( $user_saved_search_terms );
            }
            */
        }
    } // User does not have any search terms saved yet
    else {
        $user_saved_search_terms = array( $search_term );
    }

    // Finally, save the data
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'saved_search', $user_saved_search_terms );

    // What is this for?
    wp_update_user( array(
        'ID'            => $user_id
    ) );

    exit;
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_search_ss', 'search_modifications_callback' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_search_ss', 'search_modifications_callback' );
```

This way, you still will have only one `saved_search` record per user in your database.

Please note that this code hasn't been tested, so if you have any questions / comments let me know.

By the way, what if the user isn't logged-in? Are you checking for this scenario somewhere?

Comment: **Thank you!** And thanks for the comments in the code, this works virtually how I need it to, and will play around with cleaning it up on my end (that last wp_update_user isn't really necessary looking over everything). 

Looking to attach a function when I first validate for login that'll echo a modal or alert the user that they need to login to save (or set up a is_user_logged_in if statement on the initial form). Thanks for asking about that!

Comment: @Leroy if you remove / comment out the `wp_ajax_nopriv_search_ss` line, the callback function of the AJAX call will only run for logged-in users. You still will probably have to modify your JS to handle the case where the user isn't logged in (or maybe just enqueue your script only if the user is logged in, which seems easier to do).

Comment: Disregard my last comments. There's already a check in your code that validates if the current visitor is logged in (I would still remove the `wp_ajax_nopriv_search_ss` line, though.)